# PHP - Sessions security and reliability

Tags: php, security, session-variables

I'm currently learning PHP and I came up with a question about Sessions. Before making this post, I've already read some information and topics such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219944/php-sessions-security) about this subject, but the most part of them are a bit old, so I would like to make sure that I'm handling them the right way.

So, here is my **question**: Assuming the following items are true,

- Upon login, I'm using `session_regenerate_id()` to regenerate the PHP Session ID;
- Upon login, I'm creating a session variable with an encripted code (that combines the user IP, browser and some random stuff at start and end)

`$_SESSION['check'] = hash('ripemd128', $rand1 . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $rand2)`.

That value is sent to the database and, in every page, I'm checking if the value on the database matches that `$_SESSION['check']` variable;

- I force users to have cookies enabled through `ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1)`, and `ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0)` is also set;
- Upon logout, I use the following code:

`$_SESSION = array();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-259200, '/');
session_unset();
session_destroy();`

This way, and assuming that the values put into session variables are properly validated, can I trust 100% on my session variables? If not, what can I improve/change to make them safer?

The reason why I'm asking this is because when the user logs in, I save some information into session variables to avoid overloading the database with queries, so I need to make sure that they can't be compromised.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just asking if your handling them correctly? If so this probably belongs more on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Session variables can generally be trusted since they are stored and managed server side.  However, there are plenty of questions that cover the same topic on SO already, so do some research.

Comment: A hash is not an "encripted" value.

Comment: what information are you storing in your session values that needs to be protected?

Comment: @cmorrissey I'm using them to save some user "properties" (e.g username, email, last login time, ...) and some server "properties" (e.g main url, general email address, the name of other databases). So, basicaly information that won't change after the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole dance and song with *hashing* (not "encripting"!) the user agent and IP with some random values is pretty superfluous. I also don't see the point in bothering the database with it on every request.

What is that good for, what are you trying to prevent? If anything, you want to prevent session hijacking. Let's look at it in detail:

- Session hijacking means a man-in-the-middle or other 3rd party was able to steal the user's session cookie. You can prevent that simply with HTTPS, it's the only real thing you can do.
- If some malware on the user's computer stole the cookie instead of a MitM, HTTPS doesn't help. In that case the attacker would likely be sitting elsewhere entirely. In this case checking the IP would help. Checking the user agent is largely superfluous, since it can easily be imitated.
- To check the IP you simply store the IP directly in the session and do a simple `if ($_SESSION['ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`; hashing doesn't add anything to that process.
- Note that IPs may suddenly legitimately change, which would invalidate the login.
- Note that malware which is able to steal somebody's cookie might as well impersonate the user right from their own computer, in which case no sort of checking would do anything at all.

Bottom line: any sort of additional check and protection is rather useless. If you're using HTTPS and somebody is *still* able to hijack the session, you're mostly SOL either way. Don't bother. If you're not using HTTPS, start using it **now**.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I indeed want to prevent session hijacking. I don't have HTTPS for the moment, that's why I was trying to compensate it with more "checkings", but I'll use it asap. About the second part of the question, can I trust that the user won't be able to mess up with the information put into session variables (if that info was previously verified correctly and if there isn't any form that allows the user to interact with session variables)?

Comment: Yes, there's no way for a user to alter any information in a server side session (unless you write code to do so).

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thanks once again!